# Android Webview Keyboard issues

Tags: javascript, android, webview, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

we're developing a WebView based application. Since recent update of **"Android System Webview"** (v. 59.0.3071.125)  the soft keyboard has strange behaviors.

- It opens/closes slower when hopping between input controls
- the soft keyboard even sometimes dissapearing for a while (when given a ENTER to go to the next input control)
- the keyboard looks like to be stopped working at all, it is visible but it look s like not 'linked' anymore to the active input control (while the cursor is blinking in the input control)

All this was working well using "Android System WebView version 45.0.2425.95 
but not anymore. New device cannot be downgraded.

***Does anybody has a solution to:***

- keep the keyboard connect to the webview's active input control
- faster showing the keyboard popup

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems so i side-loaded earlier version of Android System WebView.
Please try uninstalling updates to Android System WebView from *Settings->Apps->Android System WebView*

And install earlier version like 55 from https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/android-system-webview-55-0-2883-91-release/
until further update comes to Android System WebView which rectifies the said problem.